# How to implement multiple inheritance with OpenZeppelin upgradeable contracts?

Tags: solidity, multiple-inheritance, hardhat, openzeppelin, evm

I'm trying to convert an existing non-upgradeable contract that has multiple inheritance into an upgradeable one. I'm following the tutorial at https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/upgradeable and the only thing I've found in docs is the following:

> Initializer functions are not linearized by the compiler like
> constructors. Because of this, each __{ContractName}_init function
> embeds the linearized calls to all parent initializers. As a
> consequence, calling two of these init functions can potentially
> initialize the same contract twice.
>
> The function __{ContractName}_init_unchained found in every contract
> is the initializer function minus the calls to parent initializers,
> and can be used to avoid the double initialization problem, but doing
> this manually is not recommended. We hope to be able to implement
> safety checks for this in future versions of the Upgrades Plugins.

I don't know what to do from here. It talks about a problem, tells a workaround, but also telling that manually isn't recommended, and also telling that it will have the safety checks in the future upgrades plugins.

So what *should* I do? It says what I shouldn't do but doesn't mention what I should do. Am I missing something?

How can I have multiple inheritance and upgradeability at the same time with OpenZeppelin contracts? (I'm extending `ERC20BurnableUpgradeable` and `[draft-]ERC20PermitUpgradeable`, and using Solidity 0.8.9, Hardhat, OpenZeppelin 4.7.3 if it helps)

Answer (score 2):

**Using Upgradeability with Multiple Inheritance in Solidity**

I didn't find any official recommendation or example tutorial on how to properly use upgradeability with inheritance in Solidity.

So I am giving a systematic approach to doing it based on my own experience.

1. If a parent contract is inherited by only one child, use the child's init() to invoke the parent's init().
2. If a parent contract is inherited by multiple child contracts, use the init() of the closest child that inherits from (wraps) the other child contracts inheriting the parent.

Consider it as bundling sections of contracts into modules. These modules are then grouped into larger modules, and this hierarchical grouping continues until you reach the most derived contract.

**It sounds a bit complicated, but the following example makes it clear.**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract Animal is Initializable {
    function __Animal_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Most base contract
        __Animal_init_unchained();
    }

    function __Animal_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Initialization logic for Animal
    }
}

contract ThinkingExtension is Initializable {
    function __ThinkingExtension_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        __ThinkingExtension_init_unchained();
    }

    function __ThinkingExtension_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Initialization logic for ThinkingExtension
    }
}

contract Human is Animal, ThinkingExtension {
    function __Human_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Human is the only child that inherits ThinkingExtension
        __ThinkingExtension_init();
        __Human_init_unchained();
    }

    function __Human_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Initialization logic for Human
    }
}

contract HorseExtension is Initializable {
    function __HorseExtension_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Most base contract
        __HorseExtension_init_unchained();
    }

    function __HorseExtension_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Initialization logic for HorseExtension
    }
}

contract FastRunnerExtension is HorseExtension {
    function __FastRunnerExtension_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        // We don't initialize HorseExtension here, because there is another child that inherits from it on the same level
        __FastRunnerExtension_init_unchained();
    }

    function __FastRunnerExtension_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Initialization logic for FastRunnerExtension
    }
}

contract SaddleExtension is HorseExtension {
    function __SaddleExtension_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        // We don't initialize HorseExtension here, because there is another child that inherits from it on the same level
        __SaddleExtension_init_unchained();
    }

    function __SaddleExtension_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Initialization logic for SaddleExtension
    }
}

contract Horse is Animal, HorseExtension, FastRunnerExtension, SaddleExtension {
    function __Horse_init() internal onlyInitializing {
        // The Horse contract wraps all contracts that inherit from HorseExtension.
        // Therefore, we initialize HorseExtension here.
        __HorseExtension_init();
        __FastRunnerExtension_init();
        __SaddleExtension_init();
        __Horse_init_unchained();
    }

    function __Horse_init_unchained() internal onlyInitializing {
        // Initialization logic for Horse
    }
}

contract Centaur is Animal, Human, Horse {
    function initialize() public initializer {
        // The Centaur contract wraps all contracts that inherit from Animal.
        // Therefore, we initialize Animal here.
        __Animal_init();
        __Human_init();
        __Horse_init();
        // Initialization logic for Centaur
    }
}
```

[Here is a visual representation of the `Centaur` contract's architecture that can help you understand how the approach works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbIr8.png)

I hope this method assists developers who might not be deeply experienced in navigating inheritance with upgradeability, at least until OpenZeppelin provides a standard way of handling it.